# Kotlin App Crashes on Start with No LOGCAT

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to learn Kotlin for Android from a slightly outdated book. After a certain step, my app crashes on startup with no errors and no LOGCAT. Tested on emulator and device. I'm sure it's a depreciation issue, but I'm not sure, and I want to learn. Here are my two activities.
MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

private const val KEY_INDEX = "index"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var trueButton: Button
    private lateinit var falseButton: Button
    private lateinit var nextButton: Button
    private lateinit var prevButton: Button
    private lateinit var cheatButton: Button
    private lateinit var questionTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var quizViewModel: QuizViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        savedInstanceState?.putInt(KEY_INDEX, quizViewModel.currentIndex)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        quizViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[QuizViewModel::class.java]

        trueButton = findViewById(R.id.true_button)
        falseButton = findViewById(R.id.false_button)
        cheatButton = findViewById(R.id.cheat_button)
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button)
        prevButton = findViewById(R.id.back_button)
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question_text)


        trueButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkAnswer(true)
        }

        falseButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkAnswer(false)
        }

        nextButton.setOnClickListener {
            quizViewModel.moveToNext()
            updateQuestion()
        }

        prevButton.setOnClickListener {
            quizViewModel.moveToBack()
            updateQuestion()
        }

        cheatButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Start intent
            val answerIsTrue = quizViewModel.currentQuestionAnswer
            val intent = CheatActivity.newIntent(this@MainActivity, answerIsTrue)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        updateQuestion()
    }

    private fun checkAnswer(userAnswer: Boolean){
        val correctAnswer = quizViewModel.currentQuestionAnswer
        val messageResId = if (userAnswer == correctAnswer) {
            R.string.correct_toast
        } else {
            R.string.incorrect_toast
        }
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            messageResId,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }

    private fun updateQuestion() {
        val questionTextResID = quizViewModel.currentQuestionText
        questionTextView.setText(questionTextResID)
    }


}
```

and CheatActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView


private const val EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE =
        "com.gabecunningham.geoquiz.answer_is_true"

class CheatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var answerTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var showAnswerButton: Button

    private var answerIsTrue = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat)

        answerIsTrue = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false)
        answerTextView = findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view)
        showAnswerButton = findViewById(R.id.answer_button)
        showAnswerButton.setOnClickListener {
            val answerText = when {
                answerIsTrue -> R.string.true_button
                else -> R.string.false_button
            }
            answerTextView.setText(answerText)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newIntent(packageContext: Context, answerIsTrue: Boolean): Intent {
            return Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me out, I'm really trying to learn this. Thank you!

Quick edit, I should explain where the changes were that caused the issue. It was the code to create the Intent in CheatActivity, and the onClickListener to start the CheatActivity from MainActivity

Comment: Probably you have a filter set up in Logcat that is hiding the relevant stack trace in the log.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It says I have no debuggable processes